# GatsbyImage for urls read from a json file

Tags: image, gatsby, gatsby-image

I have a json file that I am loading in data from to populate my webpage. For example, following is my `membersData.json`

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Person A",
    "photoUrl": null
  },
  {
    "name": "Person B",
    "photoUrl": "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=123456789012"
  }
]
```

> I use a fallback url for null images.

and I have a page `members.js`

```js
export default members = () => {
    return <>
      {data.map((entry, index) => (
        <Grid item xs={12} md={4} lg={3} key={index}>
          <MembersCard
            name={entry.name}
            photoUrl={entry.photoUrl}
          />
        </Grid>
      ))}
    </>
}
```

Where my MembersCard is a card component which minus any layouting and styling returns

```js
const MembersCard = (props) => {
    return <>
        <img src={props.photoUrl} alt= {props.name + " | Image"}/>
        <h1>{props.name}</h1>
    </>
}
```

Since all images, are known to me at compile time. I would like to know if its possible to use gatsby-plugin-image along with the traced-svg placeholder to improve upon the bad loading times for these images as they take quite a while to load in from google drive.

edit:
I now prefetch the images locally before building and am trying to push the data to graphql, via gatsby-node.js.
I found this [article](https://freddydumont.com/blog/how-to-source-images-and-data-from-json-files-in-gatsby) and built a similar setup.

```js
exports.sourceNodes = ({ actions, createNodeId, createContentDigest }) => {
  membersData.forEach( entry => {
    const {
      name,
      photoUrl
    } = entry;

    let imageName = name.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()
    let absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, IMAGE_PATH ,`${imageName}.jpg`);

    const data = {
      imageName,
      ext: '.jpg',
      absolutePath,
      extension: 'jpg'
    };

    const imageNode = ( photoUrl && photoUrl.startsWith("https://drive.google.com") )? {
      ...data,
      id: createNodeId(`card-image-${name}`),
      internal: {
        type: 'MembersCardImage',
        contentDigest: createContentDigest(data)
      }
    } : null;

    imageNode && actions.createNode(imageNode);

    const node = {
      name,
      image: imageNode,
      id: createNodeId(`card-${name}`),
      internal: {
        type: 'MembersCard',
        contentDigest: createContentDigest(entry),
      },
    }

    actions.createNode(node);
  })
}
```

yet gatsby-transformer-sharp doesn't run on my image and no childImageSharp is available on the image field. Has there been a change?

Answer (score 1):

For now, you can't use `gatsby-plugin-image` for dynamic outsource files (like yours). -

- `<GatsbyImageData>` needs to be an intern image because you need to allow Gatsby and their resolvers to treat the image. So that's not an option for you since you are using external images.
- `<StaticImage>`, as you can see from [the docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#restrictions-on-using-staticimage), doesn't accept dynamic `props`:

> **Restrictions on using `StaticImage`**
>
> The images are loaded and
> processed at build time, so there are restrictions on how you     pass
> props to the component. The values need to be statically-analyzed at
> build time,     which means you can’t pass them as props from outside
> the component, or use the results     of function calls, for example.
> You can either use static values, or variables within     the
> component’s local scope. See the following examples:

````
```
 // ⚠️ Doesn't work

 export function Logo({ logo }) {
 // You can't use a prop passed into the parent component
 return <StaticImage src={logo}>
}

```
````

However, for your use-case I would try something like:

```
const MembersCard = (props) => {
    return <>
        {props.photoUrl && <img src={props.photoUrl} alt= {props.name + " | Image"}/>}
        <h1>{props.name}</h1>
    </>
}
```

This will avoid the message:

> I use a fallback url for null images.

Since you won't be rendering the image if don't exists.

Comment: I need to render an image no matter what, so I use a fallback image instead. I have a script running before build that pulls said data from various rest and graphql apis. I can certainly predownload said Images instead of just having urls. Will that help in any way?

Comment: If the images "precached" belongs to the project (internal routes) and Gatsby can treat them using their resolvers and transformers, you will be able to use `gatsby-plugin-image`, otherwise, you will need to use the standard `<img>` tag, which I've added a workaround to avoid the error message.

Comment: So no luck even if I do pre-download the images?

Comment: Depends on when are those images being downloaded. You can try it of course to check how it behave

Comment: Since I call a fetch script before even starting the build. The files would be available just before Gatsby build is even called. If the images were available locally how would I load it in?

Comment: In that case you will be able to use `<GatsbyImageData>`

Comment: How? By making image data available from files in gatsby-node.js and then querying that data inside my page?

Comment: Exactly that way

Comment: I ended up finding this [article](https://freddydumont.com/blog/how-to-source-images-and-data-from-json-files-in-gatsby) but childImageSharp is not available on the image field... I have updated my original code.